# JSON response tampered while returning

Tags: jquery, json, spring-mvc, spring-3

I'm making an AJAX call using JQuery and Spring MVC.

The client script :

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "channelIntentionDetails.html",
    data : stringifiedSearchParameter,
    beforeSend : function(
            xhr) {

        xhr
                .setRequestHeader(
                        "Content-Type",
                        "application/json");
    },
    success : function(
            response) {

        alert("IntentionDetails : "
                + response.results);
        if (jQuery
                .isEmptyObject(response)) {
            alert("No data found for");
        }
        drawIntentionPieChart(response.results);
    }
});
```

The controller method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "channelIntentionDetails.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody
  com.lnt.sapphire.pojo.Report getChannelIntentionDetails(@RequestBody SearchParameters searchParameters) {

    System.out.println("In ReportController.getChannelIntentionDetails(...), searchParameters " + searchParameters);

    com.lnt.sapphire.pojo.Report report = channelDetailsService.getIntentionDetails(searchParameters);

    System.out.println("Returning from ReportController.getChannelIntentionDetails(...), report " + report);

    return report;
  }
```

The Report POJO :

```
public class Report {

    private Map<String, Collection<String>> parameterWiseResult;
    private Collection<String> results;
    private String result;


    public Map<String, Collection<String>> getParameterWiseResult() {
        return this.parameterWiseResult;
    }

    public Collection<String> getResults() {
        return this.results;
    }

    public void setParameterWiseResult(
            final Map<String, Collection<String>> parameterWiseResult) {
        this.parameterWiseResult = parameterWiseResult;
    }

    public void setResults(final Collection<String> result) {
        this.results = result;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Report [parameterWiseResult=" + parameterWiseResult
                + ", results=" + results + ", result=" + result + "]";
    }

}
```

The output on the server console(**results is an array**) :

```
Returning from ReportController.getChannelIntentionDetails(...), report Report [parameterWiseResult=null, results=[{ "_id" : { "SpId" : 664 , "Intention_category" : "" , "Report_Id" : 2 , "Channel_Id" : 1} , "count" : 10}], result=null]
```

But the response I get in the script(**check the alert for response.results**) :

```
{ "_id" : { "SpId" : 664 , "Intention_category" : "" , "Report_Id" : 2 , "Channel_Id" : 1} , "count" : 10}
```

Now this is causing a problem on parsing - the array[] is gone !

Any hints?

Comment: I'm kind of confused here. You have a `Collection<String> results`, but it doesn't seem to contain `String` objects. Is `Collection` your own type?

Comment: Each String in Collection<String> is actually a JSON string returned from MongoDB

Answer (score -1):

try

var reponsedata=JSON.parse(response);
 alert("IntentionDetails : "+ responsedata.results);

Comment: The issue is that JSON is not returned properly - obviously, the parse will give improper results !